# Why I get RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during operation

Tags: python, google-maps, gps

I want to get the coordinates from image GPS-metadata, but on the 9th line

> `for key, value in exif.items():`

I get an error which says:

> `RuntimeError: dictionary keys are changed during the operation`

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS


def get_exif(filename):
    exif = Image.open(filename)._getexif()

    if exif is not None:
        for key, value in exif.items():
            name = TAGS.get(key, key)
            exif[name] = exif.pop(key)

        if 'GPSInfo' in exif:
            for key in exif['GPSInfo'].keys():
                name = GPSTAGS.get(key,key)
                exif['GPSInfo'][name] = exif['GPSInfo'].pop(key)

    return exif

exif = get_exif('YOUR_IMAGE.JPG_HERE')



def get_decimal_coordinates(info):
    for key in ['Latitude', 'Longitude']:
        if 'GPS'+key in info and 'GPS'+key+'Ref' in info:
            e = info['GPS'+key]
            ref = info['GPS'+key+'Ref']
            info[key] = ( e[0][0]/e[0][1] +
                          e[1][0]/e[1][1] / 60 +
                          e[2][0]/e[2][1] / 3600
                        ) * (-1 if ref in ['S','W'] else 1)

    if 'Latitude' in info and 'Longitude' in info:
        return [info['Latitude'], info['Longitude']]



get_decimal_coordinates(exif['GPSInfo'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making changes to the dictionary while iterating through it in `exif[name] = exif.pop(key)`. Not only is this a runtime error but also an anti-pattern. Since you are accessing the dictionary inside the for loop, any changes in the dictionary will render the for loop useless and hence the `RuntimeError`. For your use case, it looks like you are trying to (sort-of) reverse the dictionary i.e. make the keys into values and vice-versa, you can easily do this with a dictionary comprehension

```py
exif = {TAGS.get(key, key): key for key, value in exif.items()}
```

and similarly for the other loop as well.